# Store Join Model Data in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, backend

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and I'm developing a backend API.

Currently, I got 2 Active Record Models called **Book** and **Genre**.

### Active Record Model

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
end

class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
    hast_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

### DB Schema Model

```
create_table :books do |t|
  t.string "title"
end

create_table :genres do |t|
  t.string "genre"
end

create_join_table :books, :genres do |t|
  t.index [:book_id, :genre_id]
  t.index [:genre_id, :book_id]
end
```

### REST POST Request

```
 # POST /book
    def create
        book= Book.new(books_params)

        if book.save
            render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', message:'Book Saved', data: book},status: :ok
        else
            render json: {status: 'ERROR', message: 'Booknot saved', data: book.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end 

    end

private
    def books_params
        params.require(:book).permit(:title)
    end
```

### QUESTION

I'd like to make an HTTP Post request to create a new book with it's **genres**. I've already tested the book insertion (without genres, just passing the book name), it works perfectly. However I'd also like to add some genre categories.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It doesn't look like there's a specific, answerable question in your question segment, and it can be hard for the community to give a specific answer in this case. What have you tried so far? Are you running into a specific error or issue? You should [edit] your question to include anything you've tried so far to implement this yourself, and why/how it hasn't worked in your case.

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut Thank you! What I'd like to achieve, is to store the data sent from a front-end form. In the "QUESTION" section I said that I've tried to send a book data (without the genres array), and it works perfectly so far. However, now I'd like to create a new book with a genres array, for instace genres_id[1, 2]. What should I do to store the genres in the "def create" section?  book = Book.new(books_params) only creates a new book, but the newly created book is not assigned with its genres in the join table. Also, I think that I need to create the genres first in the genres table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [the `has_many` and `has_and_belongs_to_many` class methods](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) create a set of `_ids` setters and getters:

```
book = Book.new
book.genre_ids = [1, 2, 3]
book.genre_ids == [1, 2, 3] # true
```

These setters will automatically create and delete rows in the join table. Since [ActiveModel::AttributeAssignment](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment.html) maps the hash argument to `.new`, `.update` and `.create` to setters in the model all you need to do is whitelist the `genre_ids` parameter:

```
def books_params
  params.require(:book).permit(:title, genre_ids: [])
end
```

Passing an empty array permits an array of [permitted scalar values](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#permitted-scalar-values) like for example numericals or strings.

Comment: so far so good, now that I expect to receive an array of genre_ids, how do I assign them to book.genre_ids ? It seems that the example you provided,you're directly assigning genres (1,2,3) I've tried book.genre_ids = books_params[:genre_ids]

Comment: You would pass a JSON object in the request body that looks like `{ "book": { "title": "AN Example Book", "genre_ids": [1, 2, 3] }}`. When you pass the whitelisted params hash with `book = Book.new(books_params)` `assign_attributes` will call the setter. You don't actually have to do anything manually. That's the whole point of mass assignment.